# JPA Instant/ZonedDateTime Database mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, java-time

I came upon a problem with java.time classes and their mapping to DB types. I want to store Instant type, but it behaves quite unintuitively.

Simple project example here: https://gitlab.com/Gobanit/jpa-time-example

I have basic entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
//    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private Instant createdAt;
//    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    private ZonedDateTime createdAtZoned;
    private LocalDateTime createdAtLocal;
    private Instant modifiedAt;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() {
        createdAt = Instant.now();
        modifiedAt = createdAt;
        createdAtZoned = createdAt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        createdAtLocal = createdAtZoned.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(String.format("Created: instant=%s, zoned=%s, local=%s", createdAt, createdAtZoned, createdAtLocal));
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        modifiedAt = Instant.now();
    }
}
```

Now, I will create and persist the entity:

```
    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("create")
    public AbstractEntity createNew() {
        System.out.println("create");
        System.out.println("ZoneId=" + ZoneId.systemDefault());
        var e = new AbstractEntity();
        em.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
```

The data in Java are as expected - system output below:

```
ZoneId=Europe/Bratislava
Created: instant=2021-12-29T14:13:55.624902400Z, zoned=2021-12-29T15:13:55.624902400+01:00[Europe/Bratislava], local=2021-12-29T15:13:55.624902400
```

However, the data in DB are not. They are all stored as the same value. The default type of the column is set to TIMESTAMP for all of them. And they are all stored as if they were LocalDateTime in application JVM timezone.

[image: jvm timezone db result]

I dont like this at all, there is no difference between these types and the "meaning" of the value is dependent on the application zone. If I look at the database without knowing which application wrote the data and what is its zone, i cannot say, what the datetime means. Even worse, if I run the application with different zone, it would assume that the values were written in its timezone, which they were not.

Some people say, the time data should be stored in UTC (which i partially agree) and they recommend setting following property, so that the values are converted to UTC zone before storing in DB by JDBC:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
```

However, this results in even worse behavior, since it applies not only to Instant/ZonedDateTime but also to LocalDateTime, which seems logically wrong to me. LocalDateTime value should not be affected by any timezone conversions at all, that is why it is LocalDateTime.

System Output:

```
ZoneId=Europe/Bratislava
Created: instant=2021-12-29T14:15:13.614799900Z, zoned=2021-12-29T15:15:13.614799900+01:00[Europe/Bratislava], local=2021-12-29T15:15:13.614799900
```

DB Result:

[image: UTC jdbc timezone db result]

I would expect one of these to happen:

1. Mapping Instant and ZonedDateTime to TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE by default. Also, Instant type should be always serialized with UTC zone - just as when printing to string or serializing with jackson. (ideal)
2. Mapping Instant and ZonedDateTime to TIMESTAMP but convert them to UTC when serializing, and back to JVM timezone when deserializing. (not ideal, but good enough)

I can override the default mapping explicitly, by uncommenting the line below.

```
// @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
```

That works fine, only Instant are not converted to UTC but take the JVM zone, just like ZonedDateTime. Technically it is totally fine, i cant see any inconsistency result happen because of that, but personally i would prefer them in UTC, so that they are always unified.
The second problem with this, is that i need to explicitly configure it for each field.

```
ZoneId=Europe/Bratislava
Created: instant=2021-12-29T14:19:14.600583400Z, zoned=2021-12-29T15:19:14.600583400+01:00[Europe/Bratislava], local=2021-12-29T15:19:14.600583400
```

[image: Timestamp with timezone db result]

In the end, I have few questions, I would really like someone to answer me :)
**

1. **Is there any way to get the ideal solution (the first mentioned)?**
2. **Is there any way to at least globally configure the type mapping?**
3. **Can you see any risks in this approach?**
4. **Is there a better or more standardized approach, that I am not aware of? What is your strategy for working with time?**

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using? What *exactly* is the data type of your column?

Comment: In this example, H2 Database is used. By default, all of the column types are TIMESTAMP. When explicitly set, the type is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot speak to JPA, but I can explain some of the JDBC issues.

> I want to store `Instant` type

The JDBC specification does not map `Instant`.

- For a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use the Java class `LocalDateTime`.
- For a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use the Java class [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

In JDBC, use `setObject` & `getObject` to exchange data-time values as *java.time* values in JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myOffsetDateTime ) ;
```

Some databases such as Postgres automatically adjust the incoming data to UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. For portable code across databases, you may want to make that adjustment in Java code.

```
OffsetDateTime myOdt = otherOdt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime myOdt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

If you have an `Instant` in hand, convert to `OffsetDateTime` for storage in a database via JDBC.

```
OffsetDateTime myOdt = myInstant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

There is no need for you to store the zoned or unzoned values in your database. You can easily adjust to time zones after database retrieval, in your Java code, as you would do for other localization needs.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = myOdt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

I see no benefit generally to using `LocalDateTime` when dealing with moments, specific points on the timeline. That class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset. Such objects contain a date with time of day only, so are inherently ambiguous. You can convert from `OffsetDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` but would be stripping away vital information while gaining nothing in return.

> they are all stored as if they were LocalDateTime in application JVM timezone.

That is a contradiction in terms. A `LocalDateTime` has no time zone or offset.

> The default type of the column is set to TIMESTAMP for all of them.

There is no default for the data type of a column. You specify the data type when creating the column. The data type does not change while inserting rows. The data type can only change if you issue an `ALTER TABLE` command.

Also, we have no idea what type you mean with the word `TIMESTAMP` since you neglected to mention your specific database. As mentioned above, the SQL standard uses four words for each of the two very different timestamp types.

> Mapping Instant and ZonedDateTime to TIMESTAMP but convert them to UTC when serializing,

No, JDBC does not require any such mapping of `Instant` nor `ZonedDateTime`.

You need to do such conversions in your Java code, outside of the JDBC calls.

The exception is that your particular JDBC driver may choose to go beyond what is required by the JDBC spec. A driver is free to handle the `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` types if it’s creators saw fit. But beware that any such code you wrote may not be portable across other JDBC drivers.

> and back to JVM timezone when deserializing.

I believe you’ll find this work much easier if, as a programmer/DBA/SysAdmin, you do most of your thinking, logging, debugging, data storage, and data exchange, in UTC (offset of zero).

Converting to `Instant` is a simple way of adjusting to UTC.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Tip: Generally write your code to *not* depend on the default time zone of your JVM, your database session, or host OS. Those defaults are not under your control as a programmer. And those defaults can change at any moment during runtime. So use a default only where called for, such as localizing to default zone of a user’s mobile device for presentation in the user-interface. And make your use of such a default explicit, always specifying the otherwise optional zone/offset arguments to various calls.

Tip: Recording the moment a row is inserted or updated is generally best left to the database.  Use a trigger where the database server captures the current moment and assigns it to the field. Then you are covered for operations outside your Java app, such as bulk data loads.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!

Comment: First, it is a shame, there is not support for these types in JDBC itself. I could do the converting in Java manually, but that would make quite a mess in the code, since I already use JPA for handling the mapping between Java and DB. The only feasible way would some custom mapper. If JDBC does not support them, I would expect that at least JPA does. OffsetDateTime might be usable, but I believe Instant is more suitable type in application logic. By TIMESTAMP, I mean TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, the databases i tried are H2 and Postgres - in the example, H2 is used.

Comment: @Gobanit I cannot speak to JPA as I do not use it. As for the JDBC mappings, I too was frustrated by the lack of support for `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` until it was explained to me by another Stack Overflow contributor that those types do not map due to the limitations of the SQL standard. Like most of the information technology industry, the standard authors were woefully uneducated in date-time handling.

Comment: @Gobanit  `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is the wrong type for tracking moments. For points on the timeline such as when a row is inserted, use only `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i would like to do. As mentioned in the question, i can override the "default" mapping to TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE, but it still isnt quite what i wanted. Technically it is fine values with different zones, but i would like all of them to be in UTC. But they are not. Not even when i use OffsetDateTime with ZoneOffset.UTC. Still somewhere (in JPA or JDBC code), it get transformed to offset (+01:00), because of Application timezone - now I am talking about H2 database case. Postgre treats timestamps with timezone differently, so there it is okay.

Comment: By default mapping I mean what column type the JPA/Hibernate generates if i leave table creation to it.

Comment: @Gobanit  Actually, H2 generally follows Postgres in most aspects. A goal of the project is to be able to work with Postgres tooling. The +01:00 adjustment you see may be coming from tooling, such as the DB admin tool you may using to view the tables. Unfortunately, many of the tools have the anti-feature of applying a default time zone to values retrieved from the database.

Comment: I thought of that too, but it is not the case, because if I run application in two different zones and create entity in each of them, I end up having these values in DB: CREATED_AT_OFFSET  
2021-12-30 01:18:52.809455+05:30
2021-12-29 20:49:09.737844+01
In postgre they would be unified to the same zone/offset based on the client session parameter.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is correct for tracking "moments"! It is actually the only one for easy work. See for example https://cockroachlabs.com/blog/time-data-types-postgresql/#timestamp-and-timestamptz Both stores SAME values. Only difference is in formatting and honestly, formatting you want to do in backend app and not to mess with database environment or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an instant in time you should manipulate it with `java.time.Instant`. You can always display it to the user with a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` Then you have to decide how to store it :

- as some sort of datetime column (depends on your DBMS)
- as long with seconds precision
- as long with milliseconds precision

If you store it with a datetime column you should use a converter either using `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.time.OffsetTime`.

I really prefer to store it in a long column as it is portable and you know exactly what it means.

Here are the converters :

```
@Converter
public class InstantAsSeconds implements AttributeConverter<Instant, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(Instant attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.getEpochSecond();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant convertToEntityAttribute(Long dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : Instant.ofEpochSecond(dbData);
    }
}

@Converter
public class InstantAsMilliseconds implements AttributeConverter<Instant, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(Instant attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.toEpochMilli();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant convertToEntityAttribute(Long dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : Instant.ofEpochMilli(dbData);
    }
}

@Converter
public class InstantAsTimestamp implements AttributeConverter<Instant, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Instant attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : Timestamp.from(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Instant convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : dbData.toInstant();
    }
}

@Converter
public class InstantAsOffsetTime implements AttributeConverter<Instant, OffsetDateTime> {

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime convertToDatabaseColumn(Instant attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }

    @Override
    public Instant convertToEntityAttribute(OffsetDateTime dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : dbData.toInstant();
    }
}
```