# I lose microseconds when Timestamp passes through my IRestResponseTransformer in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, timestamp, format, transformer-model

i will try to be more clear as possible. My project uses 2 containers to execute a service and get data from my DB2 . The first container passes input data through an IRestRequestTransformer that convert my data to be readable by the second container. The second container execute a query on my DB2 and extract the data I need. This data returns to the first container through an IRestResponseTransformer. In my case the data i'm trying to get is a Timestamp with microseconds precision that for example will be "2022-09-23 11.25.52.660135" . I can see that this Timestamp is correct when the query is executed on the second container :

[image: The parameter is called timestampInsB03 in this case]

but when it passes through the IRestResponseTransformer it gets cut and on my first container i only get "2022-09-23 11.25.52.660" without microseconds:

[image: timestampInsB03 here too]

The model of the table contains the mapping of all the columns with getter and setter like this :

```
@Column(name = "TIMESTAMP_INS_B03")
private Timestamp timestampB03;

public Timestamp getTimestampInsB03() {
        return timestampInsB03;
    }

    public void setTimestampInsB03(Timestamp timestampInsB03) {
        this.timestampInsB03 = timestampInsB03;
    }
```

I work with json and I wonder if exist an annotation like JsonFormat to specify that I need to keep microseconds or something similar. If you need more informations tell me and I will answer.